# Program Crashes in App, Need Loop Fixed

Tags: java, android, loops

This java code crashes (I think it is stuck in a loop, it gets really slow and I have trouble closing it) in the app. Everything worked before I started tinkering with the while loops. I need to make it to where when either of the EditText variables are changed, the program does math and gives an output, can someone give me an example of what I need to change?

```
    package com.software.roux.diabcalc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Insulin Calculator");
        mPrefs=this.getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    }


    public void addclick(View a) throws InterruptedException {

        if (a.getId() == R.id.add1) {

            EditText a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add1);
            EditText a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add2);

            Double currentlevel = Double.parseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
            Double carbseaten = Double.parseDouble(a2.getText().toString());
            Double oldcurrentlevel = 9999.9;
            Double oldcarbseaten = 9999.9;

            try {
                while(true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    if (currentlevel != oldcurrentlevel) {
                        if (carbseaten != oldcarbseaten) {

                            double bolusdose = Double.parseDouble(mPrefs.getString("bolus", "0"));
                            double correctiondose = Double.parseDouble(mPrefs.getString("correction", "0"));
                            double targetlow = Double.parseDouble(mPrefs.getString("low", "0"));
                            double targethigh = Double.parseDouble(mPrefs.getString("high", "0"));
                            double correctto = Double.parseDouble(mPrefs.getString("corrset", "0"));

                            double firststep = 0;


                            if (currentlevel > targethigh) {
                                firststep = ((currentlevel - correctto) / correctiondose);
                            } else if (currentlevel < targetlow) {
                                firststep = ((currentlevel - targethigh) / correctiondose);
                            } else {
                                firststep = 0;
                            }

                            double secondstep = carbseaten / bolusdose;

                            double firstplussecond = firststep + secondstep;

                            double result = 0;

                            result = firstplussecond;

                            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerobj);
                            t.setText("You Need To Use: " + result + " Units");

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            }
        }


    public void switchclick(View b){
        if(b.getId() == R.id.settings)
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so why do you have an endless loop `while(true) {` ?

Comment: That infinite `while` loop is hanging the UI thread. Instead of the loop, use a `TextWatcher` on the `EditText`, and do your calculations and result display in the `afterTextChanged()` method. Example linked at the top of your question.

Comment: That appears to be what I needed to do. Thank you.